# Коучер или коуч?

Tags: заимствования

Подскажите, какой вариант предпочесть: **коуч** или **коучер**?
Хотелось бы еще знать почему?

Answer (score 3):

Его Величество Русский Язык

Формула Дайхеса
Zuzik knows Russian uncertainly and certainly doesn't know English.
Лёлик неуверенно знает русский и уверенно не знает английский.

В. Белинский
Употреблять иностранное слово, когда есть равносильное ему русское слово, — значит оскорблять и здравый смысл, и здравый вкус.

А. Сумароков
Взращен дитя твое и стал уже детина,
Учился, научен, учился, стал скотина;
К чему, что твой сынок чужой язык постиг,
Когда себе плода не собрал он со книг?
Французским словом он в речь русскую плывет;
Солому пальею, обжектом вид зовет,
И речи русские ему лишь те прелестны,
Которы на Руси вралям одним известны.

Coach - инструктор, тренер, учитель, наставник, воспитатель...

Любезный, неуважение к родному языку от его незнания не может оправдать мещански низкопробных поцелуев в --пу американца.

К надзирателю (moderator).
Мой язык строг, но нормативен и уж безусловно грамотен и литературен. Я посмотрел исправления, сделанные надзирателями. Они спорны и бесспорны, но они ВСЕ! малограмотны. А того хуже, сложены из мнения - что есть анализ состояния желудка (не путай с суждением - вывод из факта). Я живу в США, где отношение к интеллектуальной собственности определено Суждением, не мнением. Я помещал предложения об уроках английскому. Они убраны. Согласен, если это политика портала, но об этом нужно сказать в инструктаже. И ещё но... Если этот портал зарабатывает деньги - это есть беспечная глупость, если он благотворительный, то хозяин - барин.
Я запрашиваю у смотрителей при исправлениях называть причину. Если нет - я уйду. Невелика беда? Беда огромна!!! Исправник, вернись к вопросу: как мню втискануть амуриканско слова в изык рускавай? Та струйка, которую вливаю я в помои, которыми сегодня толпа - бывшая народом русским - обливает Его Величество Русский Язык и Ея Величество Русскую Культуру, не очистит невежество, но вонь будет менее губительна.

Answer (score 1):

Есть в социальной энциклопедии:

http://voluntary.ru/dictionary/875/word/koucher-ili-kouch-konsultant
).

И.В. Кузнецова, Т.Г. Никулина, Т.В. Светенко. Обучение социальному проектированию: глоссарий. М.: 2007. 216 с.

Коучер или коуч-консультант -

это специалист (тренер, консультант), помогающий людям или группе людей по-новому осмыслить, что для них действительно важно, поставить конкретные цели и осуществить необходимые действия, а также избавиться от барьеров (ограничивающих убеждений, последствий подавленности, переживаний).

Answer (score 0):

Это относительно новый термин, в словарях его еще нет. Так что выбор за вами. В интернете встречаются два варианта. В Википедии один - коуч. Какой вариант попадет в словарь и станет официальным, сейчас сказать трудно.

Comment: Ни один из этих вариантов не должен попасть в словарь (разве что только в словарь иностранных слов). Есть же нормальные русские слова: тренер, консультант, репетитор, преподаватель. Хватит контаминаций. "Коучер" - вообще похоже на "кучер". Брр.

Comment: Должен не должен - это от нас не зависит. Это новый термин и у него иное значение, чрм у приведенных вами слов. Так что вполне вероятно слово приобретет паспорт.

Answer (score 0):

Когда  пытаешься разобраться со словом *coach*, по-русски *коуч*, то первое,  что приходит на ум, «интересно девки пляшут», — это 100 вариантов перевода с английского (американского): инструктор, тренер, учитель, наставник, воспитатель и далее по списку.

**Существительное:**
1) карета, экипаж;
2) *ист*. почтовая карета;
3) ж.-д. пассажирский вагон, разделённый на купе;
4) *амер.* пассажирский вагон с сидячими местами;
5) *амер.* второй класс (в самолёте).

**Глагол:**
1) тренировать, готовить к состязаниям; обучать;
2) тренироваться, готовиться к состязаниям;
3) *ав.* инструктировать лётчика по радио во время ночных полётов;
4) натаскивать к экзамену, репетировать;
5) заниматься с репетитором, преподавателем;
6) разучивать партии с певцами.

Тот, кто объявляет это новым направлением чего-то, или заблуждается, или лукавит.
Конечно, если в договоре на простое обучение «соблюдать то-то, делать так-то»  написать слово *коуч*, можно оплату запросить в несколько раз больше, чем со словами *преподаватель, инструктор, тренер, воспитатель.*

Comment: Это все очень интересно, но каков ответ? Вопрос был прямо поставлен: "какой вариант (из двух) предпочесть"?!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Артем, извините, что "влезла". Мне показалось, что _так_ лучше для восприятия.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: Римма, что такое "английский-американский" вообще? Если американский английский, то среди значений есть и американские, и нейтральные, и британские.

Comment: Не могу знать — _что именно_ имел автор в виду. Оставила "как есть", только поменяла тире на дефис.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: через дефис однозначно бессмыслица выходит! Лучше уж оставить как было. Наверно, автор имела в виду, что перевод с американского английского, но тут она ошиблась.

Comment: Может быть, использовать скобки?.. P. S. Если всё так плохо, давайте откачу.

Comment: Ну, если скобки, тогда хоть понятно, что утверждается. Хоть по сути это и будет ошибкой.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: ну так что, Римма, на чём остановимся? На скобках?

Comment: Пусть будут. Ваше мнение всегда ценно и к месту.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но иногда могу что-то и ляпнуть не то.))))